# combine two gstreamer pipelines

Tags: gstreamer

I have 2 gstreamer pipelines. One displays a scaled live video captured from camera on the screen and the other takes the video in its original format and saves it to a file on the disk after encoding it with the H264 format. The two pipelines are as follows;

```
# Capture and display scaled camera feed
gst-launch-1.0 -v autovideosrc ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, 
width=480,height=270 ! xvimagesink -e --gst-debug-level=3 sync=false

# Save the camera feed in its original format to disk
gst-launch-1.0 -v autovideosrc ! omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, 
stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink 
location=test.mp4 -e
```

These two pipelines work by themselves and I was wondering how i could combine them into one i.e. show the scaled video on the screen AND record the video in its original format to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed the `tee` element. not sure if I am doing this right but it seems to work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v autovideosrc ! tee name = t ! queue ! omxh264enc ! 
'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! qtmux ! 
filesink location=test.mp4 t. ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, 
width=480,height=270 ! xvimagesink -e sync=false
```

Comment: yes this is correct approach :) tee does exactly what you want, your pipe looks correct. You also used queues after tee which are necessary to move the processing of each branch into separate thread (otherwise the branches may block each other).

Comment: @otopolsky Thanks for confirming! I am new to gstreamer, so still learning the ropes! I reformatted the pipeline from its documentation example but one thing I am sure is that why the second time we refer the tee element (before the second queue), it is referred to us t. (why the period at the end?)